# Is fire the only form of permanent death?

Tags: scythe

In *Scythe*, by Neal Shusterman, most forms of death are not permanent, unless one is gleaned by a scythe. This is because healing nanites in people's blood begin the process of repair immediately, and anyone who is lethally injured is detected by near-omnipresent automated surveillance system and brought within minutes to a revival center where a highly advanced AI can repair them.

Because of this, it may be the case that fires, however infrequent, might be the only way of killing someone beyond repair. This point comes into  play near the end of the book. However, it seems that revival centers merely do very sophisticated repair; whether or not creating a copy of someone's personality within a new body is within the AI's capabilities or could truly be considered resurrection, the AI does not do this, since, to begin, with fire would not be effective in that case. It thus seems like *anything* that leads to nearly complete destruction of the brain, not just fire, would be final.

Is fire *really* the only way of killing someone permanently? Or are other methods possible, albeit extraordinarily unlikely by accident?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explored a little bit more in the second book. However, in short, if the AI can not revive you, then you are dead. There are three known ways this can happen.

1. Gleaning. By Law, the Thunderhead can not revive.
2. Complete Destruction. Physically, the Thunderhead can not revive. This is what fire falls under.
3. Inaccessibility. If the Thunderhead cannot retrieve the body in a timely manner (or at all), it can not revive.

There is a weird edge case in book two where:

> The Scythe Council is attacked by a school of sharks and their body are completely destroyed. I'm not sure if they were considered to be murdered (with finality) because they were scythes, or because the sharks destroyed them as thoroughly as a fire. Same with the people on the roof. Technically they were gleaned but it is implied that their corpses were eaten by the sharks shortly thereafter.
>
>
>  Though all that is beside the point since the Thunderhead could not have gotten to them anyway since they were on the Scythe Island.